# Why is n reduced to 0 even before the for-loop inside a recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion, cs50

I am new to programming, when I do the debug to see the flow, its showing n being reduced to 0 even before the for-loop, the function returns when n is 0 and then it jumps back to the for-loop with n=1, and somehow it's incrementing by 1 while doing for-loop.

So it looks like each time draw(n-1) is called, the whole draw() function is being executed, the for-loop too, but somehow it's able to remember what n was, even though i am only using a single variable. Or another way to look at it is that it didn't have to remember what n was, when n was 3 or 2 or 1, the for-loop is also being executed, but it was just not yet to be shown? Can someone explain this a little?

If I place the draw(n-1) after the for-loop, the flow makes perfect sense to me, although I would need to modify the condition in the for-loop to print the same thing.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void draw(int n);

int main(void)
{
    int height = get_int("Height: ");

    draw(height);
}

void draw(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    draw(n - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

debug screenshot when the function returns:

[image: debug screenshot when the function returns]

Comment: It remembers `n` because it's a local variable in a recursive function. Each instance has its own `n`.

Comment: The loop isn't executed until `draw(n  - 1);` has finished. Which means that the code recurses until the `if (n <= 0)` condition is met, only then will the loops start executing

Comment: "but somehow it's able to remember what n was, even though i am only using a single variable" -- This statement is not correct. Every time the function `draw` is called, a new variable `n` comes to life, but the variable `n` from the previous function `draw` still continues to exist. So you have several variables. Every function call of `draw` has its own variable `n`.

Comment: Learning recursion as a C beginner is a huge waste of time. There doesn't exist a single scenario where a beginner-to-intermediate programmer should ever use recursion. There barely exists any scenario where _anyone_ should use recursion. Focus on learning useful things instead. Anyway, I posted an answer...

Comment: @Lundin: Recursion is an important element in [divide-and-conquer algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm), so I wouldn't call it a waste of time. For example, it is required in the [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) algorithm. However, I do agree that iterative solutions are generally preferable to recursive solutions, when they are available.

Comment: Thank you guys, I think I understand now, it creates multiple call stacks, each has its own unique n value, and the most recent call stack must be executed first, the most inner one being draw(n=0), and then it moves on to draw(n=1) and so on.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes and beginner-to-intermediate programmers should not be implementing sorting algorithms other than for learning purposes. It is also both possible and recommended to implement said sorting algorithms by instead of recursion keeping track using a "parent/previous" pointer, either as part of the data structure or as a linked list on the side. Either of those options give vastly improved performance over recursion, in case the compiler fails to tail-call optimize, which is almost a guarantee in quicksort/mergesort since they are implemented with multiple recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the code like this to see how it gets executed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void draw(int n);

int main(void)
{
    int height = 3;
    draw(height);
}

void draw(int n)
{
    static int function_call = 0;
    function_call++;

    for(size_t i=0; i<function_call; i++)
      printf("  ");
    printf("call %d\n", function_call);

    if (n <= 0)
    {
      for(size_t i=0; i<function_call; i++)
        printf("  ");
      printf("returning from call %d\n", function_call);
      function_call--;
      return;
    }

    draw(n - 1);

    for(size_t i=0; i<function_call; i++)
      printf("  ");
    printf("printing from call %d ", function_call);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(size_t i=0; i<function_call; i++)
      printf("  ");
    printf("returning from call %d\n", function_call);
    function_call--;
}
```

Output:

```
  call 1
    call 2
      call 3
        call 4
        returning from call 4
      printing from call 3 #
      returning from call 3
    printing from call 2 ##
    returning from call 2
  printing from call 1 ###
  returning from call 1
```